# Studying a career, got a really good job offer outside that career

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, resume, career-development

I'm a student, 22 years old, currently working as an android developer, studying Computer Science and currently 2 trimesters away from graduating. I received a job offer on Networks related area, they required me to have certain certifications, CCNA and CCNP to be more specific, it will take me almost a year to finish those certifications. I started working to get them a couple of months ago.

The thing is, many of my teachers, even the ones on the CCNA courses are asking me ***why I'm studying something (Computer Science) that will mostly not add anything in that job position***, I really like networks related problems, but I love programming too, and some people say that there is no programming at all on those jobs.

The reason why I became interested in the offer, was because of the high salary (3 to 5 times the amount offered on other Android related position that I've been getting) and because I started doing some network related homework for college, and I really like it, as much as programming.

But the real question is, **will this affect my degree as Computer Science by getting experience in another area not relate to it?**

**Will this add a new skill to my curriculum and make me desirable on other job positions, maybe even related to my degree?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm coming from a computer science degree specialised in programming too and I have now 3 years of experience. What I noticed is, I actually needed some network skills to complete my projects (small company in industrial IT).

> will this affect my degree as Computer Science by getting experience
>   in another area not relate to it

I think it'll more likely give more value to it

> will this add a new skill to my curriculum and make me desirable on
>   other job positions, maybe even related to my degree

It'll definitely make you more desirable as network security is now a big part of IT projects (at least where I worked)

Comment: I was thinking that this could add some sort of value, but as many people were saying that it is not related, didn't see where it could fit, but thanks for the answer, this is sort of what I'm looking for

Comment: @LuilliCapellán Keep in mind that networking, even the networking of Cisco, tends to change over time.  A computer science degree will enhance your ability to have a long-lived career in networking, just as much as it will enhance your ability to have a great programming job, as Tomas correctly pointed out, most programming jobs eventually deal with networking in some capacity.

Answer (score 5):

So, I was studying Forensic Computing, took an internship doing Programming, which was irrelevant to my degree, and people said the same thing.

But, I was able to use the knowledge I gained in that placement to create my thesis, and then gain a job at the end of it that used both of those skills. So I would recommend doing what you find interesting, even if you don't gain direct exact skills in relation to your classes, you will gain other life skills that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm trying to get a thesis idea for college, I think I'll find a way to introduce this into it, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

> will this affect my degree as Computer Science by getting experience in another area not relate to it?

Knowledge never goes waste.

> will this add a new skill to my curriculum and make me desirable on
>   other job positions, maybe even related to my degree

Yes, yes, yes.